# How to add rows in an empty data frame in R

Tags: r

I've tried everything but I can't add rows to an empty Data Frame. I realize that the first row its added but from the second to the end I get this error:
invalid factor level, NA generated. I hope you can help me!! Thank you very much for your help!

```
   Table <- data.frame()

   for (i in 1:length(dfMoviesList)){

       ID = paste0("DF",i)
       Value = (dfMoviesList[[i]]$TITULO[1])
       Table <- rbind(Table,c(ID,Value)) 
   }
```

Comment: dfMovieList is a List of DataFrames, I want to take the title of each DF to make something similar to a hash table with an ID and a Value, the titles of the movies are strings

Comment: As I mentioned a reproducible example is useful for checking. Try `op <- options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` before running the code

Comment: You're right, that works really fine. Will I have any problem because of setting this option as False? Or it just have good benefits?

Comment: On another fresh R session, the settings will be the same as default

Comment: My solution was trying to fix the problem in your existing code.  If speed is an issue, I updated with other solutions that are faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know before hand how many rows and columns you will have in your final data.frame, it's much faster to initialize an empty matrix of the right size, fill it, and convert it to data.frame.

In the for loop you propose the Table object is dropped and created at every iteration and this gets really slow even when the number of loops is not too large. See for example:

A sample of 10000 Movies:

```
dfMoviesList <- lapply(1:10000, function(i) 
    data.frame(TITUL0= sample(1:5)))
```

Empty matrix startegy:

```
system.time({
Table<- matrix(nrow= length(dfMoviesList), ncol= 2, data= NA)

for (i in 1:length(dfMoviesList)){
    ID<- paste0("DF",i)
    Value<- dfMoviesList[[i]]$TITUL0[1]
    Table[i,]<- c(ID, Value)
}
Table<- data.frame(ID= Table[,1], Value= Table[,2])
})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.129   0.001   0.130
```

Compare to:

```
system.time({
op <- options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Table <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(dfMoviesList)){
    ID = paste0("DF",i)
    Value = (dfMoviesList[[i]]$TITUL0[1])
    Table <- rbind(Table,c(ID,Value)) 
}
options(op)
})
   user  system elapsed 
 12.316   2.855  15.180
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` before running the code

```
op <- options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Table <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(dfMoviesList)){
     ID = paste0("DF",i)
    Value = (dfMoviesList[[i]]$TITUL0[1])
    Table <- rbind(Table,c(ID,Value)) 
 }
options(op) #changes to default settings
```

#### Update

If speed is an issue, you could also try

```
ID <- paste0('DF', seq_along(dfMoviesList))
res <- data.frame(ID, Value=vapply(dfMoviesList, 
          function(x) x$TITUL0[1], numeric(1L))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
 dfMoviesList <- lapply(1:3, function(i) 
    data.frame(TITUL0= sample(1:5), val=rnorm(5)) )
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
dfMoviesList <- lapply(1:10000, function(i) 
        data.frame(TITUL0= sample(1:5)))

akrun1 <- function() { ID <- paste0('DF', seq_along(dfMoviesList))
                   data.frame(ID, Value=vapply(dfMoviesList, 
             function(x) x$TITUL0[1], numeric(1L)))
                    }
#included a data.table solution also
library(data.table)
akrun2 <- function() {DT <-  rbindlist(setNames(dfMoviesList, 
      paste0('DF', seq_along(dfMoviesList))), idcol=TRUE)
                     DT[DT[, .I[1L], .id]$V1]}   


dariober <- function(){
  Table<- matrix(nrow= length(dfMoviesList), ncol= 2, data= NA)

  for (i in 1:length(dfMoviesList)){
       ID<- paste0("DF",i)
       Value<- dfMoviesList[[i]]$TITUL0[1]
       Table[i,]<- c(ID, Value)
   }
 Table<- data.frame(ID= Table[,1], Value= Table[,2])

 }

 library(microbenchmark)

 microbenchmark(akrun1(), akrun2(), dariober(), times=20L, 
          unit='relative')
 #Unit: relative
 #     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 #   akrun1() 2.214390 2.193538 2.055775 2.173440 2.148606 1.615028    20  b 
 #   akrun2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20 a  
 # dariober() 3.226717 3.198742 2.984970 3.174609 3.139982 2.189399    20   c
```

Comment: Thank you :D It works! What are the disadvantges of setting this option as false?

Comment: @CaptainNemo I usually read the dataset with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv/read.table`.  For some plotting purpose, it may be good to read the character columns as `factor`.  I prefer character columns though.